# Why can't my " while(rs.next()) " execute all the if, ifelse,else, that I've used?

Tags: java, sql, while-loop

This is my code:

```
String queryCheck = "SELECT username, password FROM LOGIN WHERE username='" + username + "' AND password='" + password + "'";
                     stmt.executeQuery(queryCheck);
                     ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
                     while(rs.next()) {
                          dbUserName = rs.getString("username");
                          dbPassword = rs.getString("password");
                         if (dbUserName.equals(username) && dbPassword.equals(password)) {
                              MemberOption Rbs = new MemberOption();
                              Rbs.setVisible (true);
                         }

                         else if (!dbUserName.equals(username) && !dbPassword.equals(password)){
                              int notif = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Your are not Registered! USERNAME does not match Go Back? ", "Closing Program",JOptionPane.YES_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                               if(notif == 0) {
                               return;

                             }
                        else {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
               }
```

This statement is not executed:

```
else if (!dbUserName.equals(username) && !dbPassword.equals(password)){
                              int notif = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Your are not Registered! USERNAME does not match Go Back? ", "Closing Program",JOptionPane.YES_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                               if(notif == 0) {
                               return;

                             }
                        else {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Because your query only returns the row which have that `username` and `password` so only

`if (dbUserName.equals(username) && dbPassword.equals(password))` this if executed

Answer (score 0):

To execute this code

```
else if (!dbUserName.equals(username) && !dbPassword.equals(password))
{
                          int notif = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,     "Your are not Registered! USERNAME does not match Go Back? ", "Closing Program",JOptionPane.YES_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                           if(notif == 0) {
                           return;

                         }
                    else {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
```

You have to enter username and password both wrong then only it will execute! And also check that username & password you are providing is not containing extra spaces at the last or beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your logic of authentication. I would recommend the below logic for password authentication.

```
String queryCheck = "SELECT password FROM LOGIN WHERE username='" + username + "'";
stmt.executeQuery(queryCheck);
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
if(rs != null) {
    while(rs.next()) {
        dbPassword = rs.getString("password");
        if (dbPassword.equals(password)) {
            MemberOption Rbs = new MemberOption();
            Rbs.setVisible (true);
        }
        else {
            int notif = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "USERNAME and PASSWORD does not match Go Back? ", "Closing Program",JOptionPane.YES_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if(notif == 0) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}else {
    int notif = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Your are not Registered! Go Back? ", "Closing Program",JOptionPane.YES_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if(notif == 0) {
        return;
    }
}
```

According to your code in the the question, you'll not be entered into rs.next() loop if the query does not return any result.

Answer (score 0):

The query is expected to result only the username and password with respect to the condition passed to it. So obviously the if condition inside while loop will only get executed if the resulset is not null. change your username or password which is not in the table for testing the elseif condition.